# Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag in custom view, but it is actually right

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

There are many "*Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag*" related questions here, but I didn't found one matching my specific issue. This happens with a custom view I created myself named SelfieHudView, that works perfectly well in one project, but when I copied the exact same layout to other project I started getting those pesky errors and I can't see the view drawn in the layout editor design. Besides, the project builds as expected so I think it may be some Android Studio glitch, though I tried the usual "Invalidate Cache & Restart" stuff and it didn't fix it.

So my custom view is declared as this:

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView;

public class SelfieHudView extends AppCompatImageView {
    // ...
}
```

I have a selfie_hud_attrs.xml file in the res/values folder of each project with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="SelfieHudView">
        <attr name="strokeColorNeutral" format="color" />
        <attr name="strokeColorGood" format="color" />
        <attr name="strokeColorBad" format="color" />
        <attr name="fillingColorNeutral" format="color" />
        <attr name="fillingColorGood" format="color" />
        <attr name="fillingColorBad" format="color" />
        <attr name="ovalRatio" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="selfieState" format="enum">
            <enum name="NEUTRAL" value="0"/>
            <enum name="GOOD" value="1"/>
            <enum name="BAD" value="2"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

In both cases the parent layout inside the layout file is like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="my.package.SelfieRegistrationFragment">
```

The only thing that changes is "my.package" that's different for each project, but the rest is the same.

```
        <SelfieHudView
            android:id="@+id/selfie_hud_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:padding="16dp"
            app:fillingColorBad="#80C8C8C8"
            app:fillingColorGood="#80C8C8C8"
            app:fillingColorNeutral="#80C8C8C8"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/take_photo_button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:strokeColorBad="@color/red"
            app:strokeColorGood="@color/green"
            app:strokeColorNeutral="@color/lightgray" />
```

And in the original project it works as expected, but in the new one where I'm trying to reuse it it complains about the app: prefix in all those "*Color*" attributes. Unsurprisingly, if I replace these with android: as AS suggest, it will fail to build with an attribute not found error. If I leave them with app: on the other hand, it builds perfectly well, but the preview in AS doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You have tried to clean and rebuild your project? Is the custom view name _SelfieHudView_ the full package name in your XML file?

Comment: @Cheticamp tried the first several times to no avail, along with the usual invalidate cache stuff, but the second was right on the spot! Would you mind to post it as an answer so I can upvote and select it as the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the full package name for your custom view. If the package is "com.example" then specify:

```
<com.example.SelfieHudView
    ... />
```

...or...

```
<view
    class="com.example.SelfieHudView"
    ... />
```

That "view" must be all lower case. I can't find a good reference for this, but there are many samples of the technique online.

Comment: Thanks a lot, as told did this the trick. In the original project I was indeed using the package name, but as this differs in the new one I just deleted it and forgot to put the new one in place. What's confusing is that AS doesn't complain about the lack of package name itself and it builds perfectly well, only the layout designer seems to miss it.